# How can I ensure only 1 model in my django app creates a migration?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-migrations

Django 1.8 - I wrote a new model and I want to create a migration for it. I don't want the other models in the app to be created by my migration since they're proxies.

1. I tried making sure all the other models have class Meta: managed = False, this didn't stop them from showing up in my migration file.
2. In my db router, I tried to make use of allow_migrate but again, all the models showed up as "Created" in my migration file.

   ```
   def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):

       if db == 'a123admin_rw' and app_label == 'article' and model_name == 'articlestat':
           return True
       elif db == 'a123admin_rw':
           return False
       return None
   ```

What should I be doing to ensure only my model gets a migration when I run makemigrations?

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want `managed = False` models showing up in your migration? Django does not perform any operations for unmanaged models despite its presence in the migration file - i.e. they have no effect on your database.

Comment: Hmmm... good to know. Ideally I would have liked no SQL regarding those models to show up at all, reassure me, but if it really won't run that SQL, then... I suppose it'll have to do! Thanks!